# How to remove folder shortcuts from Dash files

Tags: nautilus, unity-dash, shortcuts

How can I remove folder shortcuts from nautilus dash shortcut??

You can see that some way I managed to add two new shortcuts to this menu and I do not know how to get rid of them.

[image]

Here is the list of files in application directory

```
 chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Profile_2.desktop
chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Default.desktop
chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Profile_2.desktop
chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Profile_3.desktop
chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Default.desktop
chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Profile_2.desktop
chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Profile_3.desktop
chrome-coobgpohoikkiipiblmjeljniedjpjpf-Default.desktop
chrome-coobgpohoikkiipiblmjeljniedjpjpf-Profile_2.desktop
chrome-coobgpohoikkiipiblmjeljniedjpjpf-Profile_3.desktop
chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Default.desktop
chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Profile_2.desktop
chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Profile_3.desktop
mimeapps.list
mimeinfo.cache
owa-blockthepig-69332f0881265d1bad4b167b12e3144f.desktop
owa-soundcloud-musicaudio-515e62acb4534adf9d67bd67c3aef5e8.desktop
wine-extension-application.desktop
wine-extension-appref-ms.desktop
wine-extension-chm.desktop
wine-extension-compositefont.desktop
wine-extension-crd.desktop
wine-extension-crds.desktop
wine-extension-gif.desktop
wine-extension-hlp.desktop
wine-extension-htm.desktop
wine-extension-ini.desktop
wine-extension-jfif.desktop
wine-extension-jpe.desktop
wine-extension-msp.desktop
wine-extension-png.desktop
wine-extension-rtf.desktop
wine-extension-txt.desktop
wine-extension-url.desktop
wine-extension-vbs.desktop
wine-extension-wri.desktop
wine-extension-xaml.desktop
wine-extension-xbap.desktop
wine-extension-xml.desktop
wine-extension-xsl.desktop
levan@Commodore64:~$
```

This is how my list config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks looks but the shortcut is still there

```
file:///home/levan/Documents Documents
file:///home/levan/Music
file:///home/levan/Pictures
file:///home/levan/Videos
file:///home/levan/Downloads
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Different shortcuts

The bookmarks you see in the Nautilus launcher are divided into different sections. Some are stored in the `nautilus.desktop` file (static section), others are added automatically from the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.
The last file is automatically edited and updated if you add bookmarks via the (nautilus) bookmarks menu.

#### The "Open a new Window" shortcut

This one is part of the *static* section. To get rid of it, you will have to edit the `nautilus.desktop` file:

1. First copy the file `nautilus.desktop` to your local directory (`~/.local/share/applications`):

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
   ```
2. Open the local copy with `gedit`; drag it over an opened gedit window or run:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
   ```
3. Find the line, starting with:

   ```
   Actions=
   ```
4. remove the string `Window;`
5. remove the referring shortcut section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action Window]
   Name=Open a New Window
   Exec=nautilus --new-window
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```
6. Save and close the file, log out and back in

#### The other shortcuts in your example

The other shortcuts in your example are automatically added from the file: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`. You can remove those links in two ways:

1. via GUI: Open Nautilus, from the menu, choose "Bookmarks". Remove the bookmarks you'd like to get rid of.
2. ALternatively: edit the file : `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`; remove the referring line(s).

Comment: @Levan did anything go wrong? (I noticed you unaccepted)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I can not find nautilus.desktop file in my application directory

Comment: I added the list of files in my question

Comment: @Levan This is definitely not the list from `/usr/share/applications`; your system would not be running :). better use the command `cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`

Comment: @Levan perfect, glad it works!