# How to remove shortcut directory bookmarks in homes creen?

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, shortcuts, bookmarks

How can I remove shortcut directory bookmarks in home screen ?

I follow the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584873/how-to-remove-folder-shortcuts-from-dash-files) and "Contrato Carlos" was not there to be removed.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

In your case just click `Desbloquear do lançador` (Unlock from launcher). In Ubuntu >= 18.10 it's rather `Remove from favorites`. Keep in mind that it will be still visible on your dock while it's opened.

Comment: I' m using ubuntu 16.04 with nautilus of 18.04.

Comment: I've already try your answer, but the "Contrato Carlos" still in bookmarks..